# Scheme to derive an encryption key from one's verification key, so they can reduce the decryption key from it and their signing key?

Tags: key-derivation

There is DH key exchange, but it requires an exchange before participants get to the shared secret. If Bob has only published a verifying key V<sub>B</sub>, is there a scheme where the following can be achieved?

1. Alice, from Bob's verification key V<sub>B</sub> and some nonce N, derives an ephemeral encryption key E<sub>B</sub> for Bob
2. Bob, from E<sub>B</sub>, N and S<sub>B</sub>, reduces the decryption key D<sub>B</sub>
3. Without knowledge of S<sub>B</sub>, Alice can not reduce D<sub>B</sub> from what they have

Comment: Welcome to cryptography.se. $E_A$ is not Alice encryption key in DHKE. There is a secret number of Alice $a$ and similarly for Bob $b$. Alice shares $g^a$ and Bob shares $g^b$ then they can arrive the same value $g^{ab}$. After this a key derivation function is used for derive symmetric encryption key. Your use of words make your question unclear. Could you modify your question ❓

Comment: @kelalaka Thanks for pointing out! I've reworded it.

Comment: There is https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15207 that asked the same question (basically). Apologies for a duplicate, I really couldn't find such a question until it appeared in Related.

Comment: If it satisfies you we can make it duplicate. It is a good character to look around to find it, we rarely see it from new contributors.

Comment: BIP32 specified such a scheme, while BIP32-Ed25519 is BIP32 applied to Ed25519, specified in https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7966967.